# On triple integration using spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

Original question: [Triple integral in different coordinate systems.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291054/triple-integral-in-different-coordinate-systems)

How to change to spherical coordinates in this integration:

$$
\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-x^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\int_{3-\sqrt{13-x^2-y^2}}^{-3+\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}} \,
dz\,dy\,dx,
$$

I know this question has been asked in the original post but I didn't quite get how to change here.....
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vykIu.png

So in the figure I am guessing the volume we are calculating is of the hemisphere bounded by the plane of intersection of the sphere and lower portion of the upper sphere.

If that's the case then :

all $y$ values belong to $x^2+y^2\le 9$
all $x$ values same :
$Z$ values if I am correct varies from the lower portion of the upper sphere to $z={}$ point of intersection.

Now how do I set up the spherical coordinates using this. What are the steps to analyse them?

I have referred to some examples in my book but I haven't got any clear idea on how to set them up so please help me.

Comment: It seems to me that the cylindrical coordinates are easier to use here.

Comment: It would be useful to include also link to the question where this originated: [Triple integral in different coordinate systems.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2291054)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As seen from the cross-section diagram, the volume is of a lens formed from the surfaces of two spheres. Given the vertical orientation or the symmetry around the $z$-axis, it is more convenient to set up the volume integral in cylindrical coordinates, or simply to use the shell integral,

$$V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 \int_{3-\sqrt{13-r^2}}^{-3+\sqrt{25-r^2}}
dz\> rdr d\theta$$
$$ = 2\pi\int_0^3 \left(\sqrt{25-r^2}+\sqrt{13-r^2}-6 \right)rdr$$

which can be carried out by hand.

Edit: responding to comments

Note that the equations for the two spheres are $r^2+(z-3)^2=13$ and $r^2+(z+3)^2=25$. The limits along the $z$ direction are provided by the surface equations of the two spheres, i.e. $z_1 = 3-\sqrt{13-r^2}$ and $z_2 = -3+\sqrt{25-r^2}$.

Also note the two spheres intersect at $r=3$, which can be obtained by solving the system of equations below,
$$r^2+(z-3)^2=13,\>\>\>\>\>r^2+(z+3)^2=25$$
So, use $r=3$ to set the limit for the $r$-integral.

Comment: Can you tell me how you set up the limits

Comment: @Aladdin - I added how in the body of the answer.

Comment: why is the limit of r till 3...why can't it be less for example consider any point in the shaded region then r can be less than 3

Comment: @Aladdin - The limit is the largest r that encloses the area being integrated, which is a circle of radius 3

Comment: Last doubt. Why do you mean by area here. Aren't we calculating volume

Comment: @Aladdin - I was referring to the integral area in the  polar plane after the z-integral is done